# MergeAdapter layout issue in a fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, commonsware-cwac

I'm trying to make a layout in Android with Fragments. I started to use Commonsware's [MergeAdapter](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-merge) but I'm having a weird bit of trouble. The layout worked fine before, but now I get this:

[image]

There are a couple problems: The white strip should have text going all the way across its length. I set the TextView with a white background to make sure the width was being set correctly. The checkbox right below it should also say "Issue?" but it's trying to wrap the text for some reason.

Here is the layout code that is being added:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Instructions" />
    <TextView android:id="@+id/tvInstructions" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Instructions go here" android:textSize="32dp" android:background="#FFFFFF"></TextView>
    <LinearLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:orientation="horizontal" android:paddingTop="24dp">
        <CheckBox android:id="@+id/cbIssues" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_width="0dp" android:text="Issues?" />
        <TextView android:id="@+id/tvStation" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_weight=".5" android:text="Station:" />
        <Spinner android:id="@+id/spStation" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_weight=".5"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Pending data" />
</LinearLayout>
```

and here's how I'm inflating it inside the Fragment's onActivityCreated:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
MergeAdapter _adapter = new MergeAdapter();

View observationHeaderView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.observationheader, getListView(), false);
_adapter.addView(observationHeaderView);
```

I get a feeling it has something to do with how I'm inflating the layout. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears my problem was with `layout_width` being `match_parent` in certain places in my header, when it should have been `wrap_content`. The following worked:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Instructions" />
    <TextView android:id="@+id/tvInstructions" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Instructions go here" android:textSize="32dp" android:background="#FFFFFF"></TextView>
    <LinearLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:orientation="horizontal" android:paddingTop="24dp">
        <CheckBox android:id="@+id/cbIssues" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="Issues?" />
        <TextView android:id="@+id/tvStation" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_weight=".5" android:text="Station:" />
        <Spinner android:id="@+id/spStation" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_weight=".5"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Pending data" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `match_parent` for `android:layout_height` for something going into an `AdapterView`, such as your root `LinearLayout`.

You might also consider temporarily putting your header layout outside the `ListView` (e.g., in a vertical `LinearLayout` also holding the `ListView`) and get it debugged before adding the complication of having it in the `ListView`.

Beyond that, fire up Hierarchy View (Eclipse perspective or standalone edition) and try to figure out where your layout rules are going wrong.

Also, I am uncertain how well your `Spinners` will work inside of a `ListView` on Honeycomb.

Comment: Changing the layout_height didn't fix it. I put the header outside of the ListView and it works just fine. It only does this inside the ListView. I tried Hierarchy View before coming here, and I couldn't tell what was going on. The element is the correct width, as best I can tell. And the spinners work fine.

Comment: It works fine if I don't add any other views to the ListAdapter.

Comment: @Andrew Koester: If you create a full sample project that demonstrates the problem, I can take a look at it.

Comment: Ah-hah. While creating the sample project, it appeared to work fine until I selected a value from one of the Spinners. I assume this is the root of my problem, I'll just replace it with a button and a radio button alert dialog.

Comment: Stranger and stranger. It still does it with a textbox, once I change the value.

Comment: @Andrew Koester: IMHO, `ListView` is really not designed for things like `EditText` and `Spinner`. If you don't have many rows, you might just put all of them in a vertical `LinearLayout` and wrap that in a `ScrollView`.

Comment: @CommonsWare i am using merge adapter to show my list of data's in vertical scroll is it possible to show it in horizontal list view if can u please share the lib link